# RSpec "Undefined method" order dependency error in Rails 4 in a spec that works in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have been using a testing workflow in Rails 3.2 for a few months that I picked up from a screencast by Rem Zolotykh.  It is simple and useful for verifying the basic components of the Rails stack.  However, I am using it in Rails 4.0.0 for the first time and I am getting an order dependency error where I have not had one before.  This is the UsersController spec:

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe UsersController do 
  describe 'POST create' do
    let!(:user) { stub_model(User) }
    it 'sends new message to User class' do # this is the one that fails intermittently
      params = {                            # call this spec 1
        'first_name' => 'Test',
        'last_name' => 'Tester',
        'email_address' => 'test@test.com',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'password_confirmation' => 'secret'
      }
      User.stub(:new).and_return(user)
      User.should_receive(:new).with(params)
      post :create, user: params
    end
    it 'sends save message to user model' do # this one always passes
      User.stub(:new).and_return(user)       # call this spec 2
      user.should_receive(:save)
      post :create
    end
  end
end
```

This is the UsersController:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    user = User.new(params[:user])
    user.save
    render nothing: true
  end
end
```

Should be very simple.
However, when the random test order fires Spec 2 first, then spec 1 passes.  If spec 1 is fired first, it fails but spec 2 still passes.
The failure error for spec 1:

```
1) UsersController POST create sends new message to User class
 Failure/Error: post :create, user: params
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `save' for #<User:0x007f9d1b6baf98>
 # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:8:in `create'
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:32:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I am using rspec-core 2.13.1 and rspec-rails 2.13.2.
I've searched high and low and I have found nothing.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think so.

In case 1, `User.new` has been stubbed to return the memoized stub_model. The stub model doesn't have a `save` method, though, so you get an error when you do the `post :create`, which in turns invokes `new` and then calls `save` on the result.

If you execute the second spec 1st, it creates an expectation on the `stub_model` that `save` will be called, so case 1 passes.

What I'm confused by is that `let` should not be caching results across examples, as described in https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let, so I would think case 1 should still fail even if case 2 is executed first.

As for why this would be different between 3.2 and 4.0, I have no idea. Good luck.